# On existing record skip otherwise insert data Laravel Eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, insert, eloquent, duplicate-data

I have the following table structure which I seed dynamically from API

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('reports', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('program_id')->unique();
        $table->date('date');
        .
        .
        .
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

on each API request I get back an array of Data and I try to save theme in the table above. If program_id exist I would like to ignore those records and save the new one.
I've been looking around but I do not find the best way the validate the specific value in retrieved array

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '528027827' for key 'reports_program_id_unique
```

The way as I save my records

```
// $datas are the field datas from API
foreach ($datas as $data) 
{
      $report = \Td\Reports\Reports\Reports::firstOrCreate($data);
}
```

How to skip insert on existing program_id and insert just the new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `firstOrCreate()`:

```
$data = ['program_id' => 528027827, ...];

$report = Report::firstOrCreate($data);
```

Comment: Having tried but still getting `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '528027827' for key 'reports_program_id_unique`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that you're specifying the `program_id` as needing to be unique, then sending an array with data which has the same `program_id`

You either need to remove the `unique` key from the database, remove the duplicates from your array, or if `program_id` is the primary key, set it on the model by setting `protected $primaryKey = 'program_id';`